# ERROR: Content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am trying to generate jaxb classes using xsd file but it throws me the following error.

**parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Content is not allowed in trailing section.
  line 98 of /eclipse-workspace/jaxb/response%20(1).xsd
Failed to parse a schema.**

this is my file:

[response.xsd](https://gist.github.com/singhakash009/f222709cd65723a452c8bd2f1f067b00)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your file and validate it in [XML VALIDATION](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/), on line 98 you have a not supported character

[image: here]

After removing it and validating again on the xml validation, the error did not happened

You have to investigate what(or why) is generating this character, post some info here or ask another question.